# How to detect whether a file is already synchronized with the cloud?

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-photos

is it possible on Android to know whether a file/photo is already synchronized with the google drive or google-photos? 
I can't find anything in file metadata that says the file is synchronized

Answer (score 0):

There isnt an official way and it can change anytime.
On Windows you can look at the icon. It has a little check when its in sync and there is a way to get the icon with the win32 api.

Comment: Ok, but How can I to that on android?